# C++: A must-have default superclass constructor for inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, superclass, default-constructor

Is it obligatory to have a default constructor in a superclass to have the possibility to inherit from it? Suppose every derived class constructor is calling one of superclass constructors explicitly, providing the right parameters - will such code work?

Comment: The answer is, of course, it depends. Do you have, for instance, any kind of data in your "superclass"?

Comment: @MrLister, I'm talking about the simplest example you can imagine. Please specify what do you mean by "it depends".

Comment: See the answers. If there are no members to initialise in parent class, there's no need the write any constructors at all. The compiler will implicitly create a default constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it obligatory to have a default constructor in a superclass to have the possibility to inherit from it?

No.

If you don't have default constructor in the base class, you need to call the base class constructor with argument(s) *explicitly* from the derived class constructor's member-initialization list.

Example,

```
class base
{
   public:
     base(std::string const & s, int n);
};

class derived : public base
{
   anotherClass obj;
   public:
     derived() : base("string", 10), obj(100) 
     {       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ member-initialization list
     }
};
```

Note the syntax of `base("string", 10)`. It invokes the base class's constructor, passing `"string"` as first argument and `10` as second argument.

Also notice `obj(100)` which initializes the member variable which is of type `anotherClass` : `obj(10)` invokes the constructor of `anotherClass` which takes `int` as argument.

Comment: Which notably means that the compiler will not automatically generate a Default Constructor for the derived classes. Just sayin'.

Comment: @MatthieuM. If you provide any constructor, the compiler will not automatically generate one.  If the base class has no default constructor, and the compiler tries to generate a default constructor for the derived, it will be an error.

Comment: @JamesKanze: yes, I was attempting to point out that if the base class has no default constructor then you necessarily need to provide at least one constructor for the derived class.

Comment: why is `obj(100)` before the `{` ? In other words, is there a difference if you place obj(100) in the derived constructor body?

Comment: @clankill3r: Yes. That would be an error if you put that in the ctor-body. Read about member-initialization-list to understand this.

Answer (score 3):

Provided that

- The default constructor is not called explicitely
- All subclasses invoke on construction the user-defined super-class constructor with parameters

it is not mandatory to write a default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If every constructor of the children classes use an explicit constructor of the parent, there is no need for the parent to have a default constructor.

If you have a class with no default constructor, everyone is forced to use an explicit constructor upon instantiation, right? It's the same concept, if all the children make sure the default constructor is never called, then there is no need to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

No, with one possible exception.  Normally, the base class constructor
will be called by the derived class immediatly above it, using the
arguments provided by that derived class (if any).  If all of the
immediate derived classes initialize the base class explicitly, then no
default constructor is needed.

The one possible exception is if you inherit virtually from the base
class.  In that case, it is not the immediate derived class which 
initializes the base class, but the most derived class.  And depending
on how your class hierarchy is organized, you may not want the most
derived class to know about the base; it should be sufficient for the
most derived class to only know about the classes it directly inherits
from.  (Of course, this is an ideal, and is not always the case.)
Luckily, as it happens, almost every time this occurs, the base is an
abstract class without data (and thus with a default constructor).  But
it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: But then the possible exception is not an obligation, as far as the language is concerned. The language doesn't force you to have a default constructor even in this case. It is more about the design of the class hierarchy, and the programmer choice.

Comment: @Nawaz The language doesn't force you to have a default constructor, but it does force you to make the base class known to the most derived class if you don't have a default constructor.  Depending on the architecture, that may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need a default constructor. The following compiles and runs, with or without the private Default constructor.

```
class A {
public:

  A(int i) {
    m = i;
  }

private:

  A() { } // This line can be commented out. Included only to make point

  int m;
};

class B : A {
public:

  B(int i) 
    : A(i) 
    {
    }

};

int main() {
  B b(10);
}
```